# What are the six in SN 1.70?

Tags: pali-canon

The sutta quoted below has a riddle about the six.

What are the six? And why?

What is the message of the sutta?

[SN 1.70](https://suttacentral.net/sn1.70/en/bodhi) translated by Bhikkhu Bodhi:

> “In what has the world arisen?
>   In what does it form intimacy?
>   By clinging to what is the world
>   Harassed in regard to what?”
>
> “In six has the world arisen;
>   In six it forms intimacy;
>   By clinging to six the world
>   Is harassed in regard to six.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Cha Chakka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/26.6-Chachakka-S-m148-piya.pdf) is another Sutta which has a play of the number 6. Here more elaboration is given on what each set of 6 is.

[image: Cha Chakka Sutta]

Source: [Cha Chakka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/26.6-Chachakka-S-m148-piya.pdf)

The Singhala translation is less of a riddle than the English. English retranslation is mine:

> (අධ්‍යාත්මික ආයතන) සය උපන් කල්හි ලොව උපන්නේ නම් වේ.

When the 6 sense bases arises the world arises

> (රූපාදී බාහිර ආයතන) සයෙහි සඞගමය කෙරෙයි.

By non-reaction to the external sense objects, the world is stilled

> (අධ්‍යාත්මික ආයතන) සයම ප්‍රත්‍යය කොට ගෙන

By means of the 6 sense bases

> (බාහිර ආයතන) සයෙහි ලෝ වැසි තෙම පෙළෙයි (වෙහෙසෙයි)

The 6 external sense objects trouble the worldlings

[ලොක ( හෙවත් ජස්සුලොක ) සූත්‍රය](https://suttacentral.net/sn1.70/si/zoysa)

අධ්‍යාත්මික ආයතන - world - internal senses - eye, ear, ....

බාහිර ආයතන - external sense objects

So what is covered here is the 1st 2 items in the list of items in [Cha Chakka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/26.6-Chachakka-S-m148-piya.pdf):

- the 6 internal senses
- the 6 external senses

Answer (score 2):

In what has the world arisen? Kismiṃ loko samuppanno?

> And what, bhikkhus, is the **origin of the world (lokassa samudayo)**?
>
> 1. In dependence on the
>      **eye and forms, eye-consciousness** arises. The meeting of the three is
>      contact. With contact as condition, feeling comes to be; with feeling
>      as condition, craving; with craving as condition, clinging; with
>      clinging as condition, existence; with existence as condition, birth;
>      with birth as condition, aging-and-death, sorrow, lamentation, pain,
>      displeasure, and despair come to be. This, bhikkhus, is the origin of
>      the world.
> 2. In dependence on the **ear and sounds** …
> 3. In dependence on the **nose and
>      odours** …
> 4. In dependence on the **tongue and tastes** …
> 5. In dependence on the
>      **body and tactile objects** …
> 6. In dependence on the **mind and mental
>      phenomena, mind-consciousness** arises. The meeting of the three is
>      contact. With contact as condition, feeling comes to be; with feeling
>      as condition, craving; with craving as condition, clinging … existence
>      … birth; with birth as condition, aging-and-death, sorrow,
>      lamentation, pain, displeasure, and despair come to be. This,
>      bhikkhus, is the origin of the world.
>
>    [SN 12.44](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.44/en/bodhi)